# Thread communication theory

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, theory

What is the common theory behind thread communication? I have some primitive idea about how it should work but something doesn't settle well with me. Is there a way of doing it with interrupts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Really, it's just the same as *any* concurrency problem: you've got multiple threads of control, and it's indeterminate which statements on which threads get executed when.  That means there are a large number of POTENTIAL execution paths through the program, and your program must be correct under all of them.

In general the place where trouble can occur is when state is shared among the threads (aka "lightweight processes" in the old days.)  That happens when there are shared memory areas,

To ensure correctness, what you need to do is ensure that these data areas get updated in a way that can't cause errors.  To do this, you need to identify "critical sections" of the program, where sequential operation must be guaranteed.  Those can be as little as a single instruction or line of code; if the language and architecture ensure that these are *atomic*, that is, can't be interrupted, then you're golden.

Otherwise, you idnetify that section, and put some kind of guards onto it.  The classic way is to use a *semaphore*, which is an atomic statement that only allows one thread of control past at a time.  These were invented by Edsgar Dijkstra, and so have names that come from the Dutch, *P* and *V*.  When you come to a *P*, only one thread can proceed; all other threads are queued and waiting until the executing thread comes to the associated *V* operation.

Because these primitives are a little primitive, and because the Dutch names aren't very intuitive, there have been some ther larger-scale approaches developed.

Per Brinch-Hansen invented the *monitor*, which is basically just a data structure that has operations which are guaranteed atomic; they can be implemented with semaphores.  Monitors are pretty much what Java `synchronized` statements are based on; they make an object or code block have that particular behavir -- that is, only one thread can be "in" them at a time -- with simpler syntax.

There are other modeals possible.  Haskell and Erlang solve the problem by being functional languages that never allow a variable to be modified once it's created; this means they naturally don't need to wory about synchronization.  Some new languages, like Clojure, instead have a structure called "transactional memory", which basically means that when there *is* an assignment, you're guaranteed the assignment is atomic and reversible.

So that's it in a nutshell.  To really learn about it, the best places to look at Operating Systems texts, like, eg, [Andy Tannenbaum's text](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136006639).

Answer (score 5):

The two most common mechanisms for thread communication are shared state and [message passing](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/193).

Answer (score 3):

THe most common way for threads to communicate is via some shared data structure, typically a queue. Some threads put information into the queue while others take it out. The queue must be protected by operating system facilities such as mutexes and semaphores. Interrupts have nothing to do with it.

Comment: There are lock-free queues for use in a few carefully controlled  situations.  But you do still need some help from the OS to keep your queue reader from busy-waiting.

Comment: "nutexes and senaphores" should be "mutexes and semaphores"

Answer (score 1):

To communicate between threads, you'll need to use whatever mechanism is supplied by your operating system and/or runtime.  Interrupts would be unusually low level, although they might be used implicitly if your threads communicate using sockets or named pipes.

A common pattern would be to implement shared state using a shared memory block, relying on an os-supplied synchronization primitive such as a mutex to spare you from busy-waiting when your read from the block.  Remember that if you have threads at all, then you must have some kind of scheduler already (whether it's native from the OS or emulated in your language runtime).  So this scheduler can provide synchronization objects and a "sleep" function without necessarily having to rely on hardware support.

Sockets, pipes, and shared memory work between processes too.  Sometimes a runtime will give you a lighter-weight way of doing synchronization for threads within the same process.  Shared memory is cheaper within a single process.  And sometimes your runtime will also give you an atomic message-passing mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

If you're really interested in a *theory* of thread communications, you may want to look into formalisms like the [pi Calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi-calculus).